# How to add comment to cart page

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

I need to add comment to cart page using observer . I need to know better way. Is it better to add custom option. i have tried using following code but no success

```
$option = array(
'is_delete' => 0,
'is_require' => false,
'previous_group' => 'text',
'title' => 'Shipping Description',
'type' => 'field',
'price_type' => 'fixed',
'price' => '0.0000'
);
 $options->addOption($option);
$options->saveOptions();
```

I am using checkout_cart_product_add_after observer . comment is only for display purpose so it is custom option is better or any other option

Comment: how can i Add custom option after product add to cart ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution from this link

[Creating Custom option and prize to just added product to cart using observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/creating-custom-option-and-prize-to-just-added-product-to-cart-using-observer/1382#comment22688_1382).
It might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the possibility for the customer to add a comment, you can greatly use the "add gift message" option, which magento offers out of the box. Just change the translation

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, for the file: template/checkout/cart.phtml 
 Add the new heading along with other heading for cart items.

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('Comments') ?></th>
```

In the file: template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
Add a new column

```
<td class="a-center">
<textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $_item->getItemcomment() ?></textarea>
</td>
```

For Older version of Magento it would be:

```
<td class="a-center">
<textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $this->getItemItemcomment($_item) ?></textarea>
</td>
```

The next step is to save the comment in DB, when customer update the cart.
So add a new field ‘itemcomment’ in the tabel ‘sales_flat_quote_item’. (For older version of Magento the table would be ‘sales_quote_item’)

Now we are going to add the code which will do the DB operation. For this we will need to modify the file:app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php (Note: If you are planning to upgrade your Magento setup, copy this file to local & modify.)

Here we need to add some code to the function updateItems(), such a way that the function should now look like below:

```
public function updateItems($data) {
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
 foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
     $item = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
     if (!$item) {
         continue;
     }
     if (!empty($itemInfo['remove']) || (isset($itemInfo['qty']) && $itemInfo['qty']=='0')) {
         $this->removeItem($itemId);
         continue;
     }
     $qty = isset($itemInfo['qty']) ? (float) $itemInfo['qty'] : false;
     if ($qty > 0) {
         $item->setQty($qty);
     }
     /* Start: Custom code added for comments */
     if(!empty($itemInfo['comments'])) {
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        # make the frame_queue active
    $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET itemcomment = '".$itemInfo['comments']."' where item_id = $itemId"; $write->query($query);
        $item->setItemcomment($itemInfo['comments']);
     }
     /* End: Custom code added for comments */
 }
 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_after', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
 return $this;
}
```

Showing the comment in Admin -> View Order

Add a new function getItemcomment() to the file below: 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php 
If you are on verstion 1.5 or later.. add it to the file below. 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php

```
public function getItemcomment($item) {
    $itemId = $item->getId();
    $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_flat_order_item` o LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.quote_item_id = q.item_id WHERE o.item_id = $itemId";
    # For older versions of Magento
    /* $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_order_entity_int` o LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.value = q.entity_id WHERE o.entity_id = $itemId AND o.attribute_id = 343"; */      
    $res = $write->query($query);
    while ($row = $res->fetch() ) {
        if(key_exists('itemcomment',$row)) {
            echo nl2br($row['itemcomment']);
        }
    }
}
```

To add the comments column to the items edit the .phtml file below: 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml

Add header for items:

```
<th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Comments') ?></th>
```

To add Column with comments edit the .phtml file below:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml 
Add a column for item comments.

```
<td><?php echo $this->getItemcomment($_item) ?></td> <!-- New column added for item comments -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a free extension that you should take a look at: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemaven-ordercomment.html