# Get Custom Option Text Field Value in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I'd like to retrieve the contents of the text field (custom option) that the customer entered at the product page.  I have tried functions such as: `getValue`, `getPost`, `getMyCustomValue`, `getAttributeText` and a few others.

```
$_options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
//var_dump($_options,true);
foreach ($_options as $option) {
    //print_r($option);
    $title = $option->getDefaultTitle();
    //foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) {
    //  print_r($value->getData());
    //}     
    $value = $option->getOptionText();
    echo "<br />".$title." - ".$value."<br />";
}
```

I am working within /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php in Magento 1.9.1.  Any idea which function is used to "get" the text field of a custom option?

Comment: Why are you working in this file? You shouldn't edit the core! That being said, `$product->getCustomOption($code)['value']` should work, but only if this product instance has already been prepared with the user data.

Comment: Just trying to adjust pricing on a product.  I will be reverting and moving to the appropriate location.  What is $code? Does that need to be changed?

Comment: `$code` is the code of the custom option. If you want to access all custom options, use `$product->getCustomOptions()` instead to get an array. But do yourself a favor and do it right from the beginning: what you need is an observer for `catalog_product_get_final_price` (as explained here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74463/243)