# How to add data in item cart page

Tags: cart

I want to add data in cart [image]

How can i do this without change core files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by Observer.
 **1.You need to add Following Event in Config.xml**

```
<sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
<observers>
<hackathon_presentation>
<type>singleton</type>
<class>modulename/observer</class>
<method>salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore</method>
</hackathon_presentation>
</observers>
</sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
```

**In Observer.php add below mentioned code **

```
 public function salesQuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore($observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $quote_items = $quote->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($quote_items as $item) {
            $additionalOptions = array(
                array(
                    'code'  => 'my_code',
                    'label' => 'This text is displayed through additional options',
                    'value' => 'ID is ' . $item->getProductId() . ' and SKU is ' . $item->getSku()
                )
            );
            $item->addOption(
                array(
                     'code'  => 'additional_options',
                     'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

For More see [Here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1efPznQSVTrT1HAD1xQvCPC-Tgvr8jYok4X7ZEJhm9jE/edit#slide=id.gd03b59c1_016) and  [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/creating-custom-option-and-prize-to-just-added-product-to-cart-using-observer/1382#comment22688_1382)