# Create custom options in event observer magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-options, addtocart, custom-prices

I want to create new custom option for quote item in my observer. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $price = '100'; //set your price here
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

I am setting custom price but I also need to set some custom options. I have created observer on checkout_cart_product_add_after event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` event if you want to set custom option

In this event you can easily get `$product` object by using

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
```

set your custom option by

```
$infoOptions[] = array(
                            'label' => "YOUR_LABEL",
                            'value' => "YOUR_VALUE",
                        );
```

Add this custom option by

```
 $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($infoOptions));
```

just it,

Comment: thanks for your comment I will definitely give a try to your method and mark your answer correct if it works. I solved my problem with by creating an observer on  sales_quote_collect_totals_before event.
source: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/creating-custom-option-and-prize-to-just-added-product-to-cart-using-observer

Only trick was the declaration of observer... In magento 2 I declared it in my event.xml file.